# LayoutUpdated event has stopped firing. Handlers are in place, any ideas?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, layout

I have a control which allows the user to add and manipulate n graphical and text layers.   The layers are each usercontrols that are added to the parent control's canvas.  I use the parent control's LayoutUpdated event to refresh transform specific variables and other stuff.  With no change to the handler method, the LayoutUpdate event stopped firing. I've obviously done something that caused it, but I haven't been tinkering with anything that can logically tie to this new problem.  Any ideas are appreciated - thanks. 
JUST TO CLARIFY:  I'm not asking for a solution - just an anecdote of experience with something similar - That will probably be more helpful than you can imagine.  Thanks

Comment: we have no clue what you may have done without seeing relevant code.

Comment: Just wondering if anyone had experienced it before - often another's experience is valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause, in this case, was a WPF UserControl (kid) defined in xaml at design time inside a canvas without any dependency property values set.  The canvas is inside another usercontrol of different type (mom).  At runtime, a mom is instantiated and her kid is sized, positioned, and made visible within the canvas of mom based on the runtime size of mom as well as calling arguments that denote whether or not kid is to be visible. This instance of kid is only sized and positioned if it is  requested to be visible,  if not, it is only hidden (not sized, not positioned).
The presence of this instantiated, but unsized and unpositioned element within the canvas of mom was causing the failure of layoutupdated events to fire.  This situation effected not only the instance in question, but all other instances  created at runtime in the project afterward.  (NOTE - no exception was raised)

The solution appropriate for this circumstance was to  explicitly size and place this element within the canvas - even if it is not needed.  The layoutupdated events  then fire as expected.  I would love to provide a more profound and generalized answer, but perhaps wiser people can include their insight as well.  Thanks